# Is it possible to use an Olympus OM-SYSTEM S ZUIKO lens on the Canon A1 film SLR?

Tags: lens, canon, lens-adapter, olympus, film-cameras

I can't find a suitable adapter from OM to FD.

Is it not possible due to the flange distances/etc?

I know there are OM to EF adapters though, but I want to use this Olympus OM lens on my film Canon A1 SLR instead of my Canon 6D as it is easier to manually focus with the split focus screen on the A1.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The flange distances don't appear to be the hanging point. The OM registration distance is only 0.5mm shorter than the Nikon F mount. There are Nikon F to Canon FD adapters. It seems to be more of an issue with the opposite direction of rotation for the two respective lens mounts combined with specific clearance issues due to the FD breech lock style mount and the OM mount's deep flange lugs that extend 4.5mm behind the flange contact surface.

https://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/4114334#forum-post-59083597

There has been at least one successful DIY example that was used to connect an OM lens to an FD to micro four-thirds focal reducer. It took a lot of machining, drilling and tapping, and parts from two other adapters to make it work.

https://www.mu-43.com/threads/olympus-om-to-canon-fd-adapter.72160/

Comment: So, there's no easy way to get the OM to fit FD... Guess it's a no go then. Thanks.